# Refer to page numbers where table is referenced

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm using autoref to refer to tables in the text, e.g.

> In `\autoref{tab:main_result}`, you can see ...

I'd like to be able to refer to a variable that lists the pages that `tab:main_result` is called on. The ultimate goal is to be able to put that reference in the table note (e.g. "For discussion of this table, see page XX").

Is this possible? I know that I could refer to the section in the table notes, but I'd like to be able to refer to the page.

Comment: How about `\pageref{tab:main_result}`?

Comment: That references the page the table is on, not the page the table is referred to on.

Comment: AFAICT, LaTeX doesn't provide any built-in facilities for keep tracking of where some item (e.g., a `table`) is being cross-referenced elsewhere in the document.  A preprocessor approach might offer a viable solution. pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX don't provide a built-in preprocessor facility, but LuaLaTeX does. Are you able to switch to and use LuaLaTeX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{table} \caption{A}\label{tab:main} \end{table}
\clearpage \null \clearpage

In \vref{tab:main}, you can see \dots

For a discussion of \cref{tab:main}, see \cpageref{tab:main}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

When I first read this I thought that the question was asking for a command that gave the list of pages that contain a reference to a given table. That is, an analogue of [backref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/backref) for `\autoref` instead of for `\cite`. Rereading the question it probably does not ask for this but, nonetheless, I thought this an interesting question and the code below is one way of providing this functionality.

The code works by redefining the `\autoref` command so that whenever it is called it first adds the current page number to a corresponding [latex3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3) sequence. At the end of the document this sequence is saved to the aux file. Once the document has been compiled at least once the command `\pagerefs{...}` can be used to print the list of pages that the reference appears on. So, for example, the MWE below produces:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\PageReferences{mm}{
  \seq_if_exist:cF {g__pages_#1_seq}{
    \seq_new:c {g__pages_#1_seq}
    \seq_gset_from_clist:cn {g__pages_#1_seq} {#2}
  }
}
\RenewDocumentCommand\autoref{sm}{
  \seq_if_exist:cF {g_pages_#2_seq}{
    \seq_new:c {g_pages_#2_seq}
    \AtEndDocument{
      \iow_now:cx { @auxout } {
        \token_to_str:N \PageReferences{#2} { \seq_use:cn {g_pages_#2_seq}{,}}
      }
    }
  }
  \seq_if_in:cxF {g_pages_#2_seq} {\thepage} {
        \seq_gput_right:cx {g_pages_#2_seq} {\thepage}
  }

  % now call the real autoref, which is really \HyPsd@autoref
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\csuse{HyPsd@autoref}*{#2}}{\csuse{HyPsd@autoref}{#2}}
}
\NewDocumentCommand\pagerefs{m}{
  \seq_if_exist:cTF {g__pages_#1_seq}{
   \seq_use:cnnn {g__pages_#1_seq} { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ,~and~ }
  }{??}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{E:1} 1+1=2 \end{equation}
  Look at \autoref{E:1}! It occurs on pages \pagerefs{E:1}.

  \lipsum

  Look at \autoref{E:1}

  \lipsum

  Look at \autoref{E:1}

  \lipsum

  Look at \autoref{E:1}

  \lipsum

  Look at \autoref{E:1}

  \lipsum

  Look at \autoref{E:1}

  \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer is fine and gives what is seams that OP looking for, however, i can't imagine why someone will repeat the same equation with the same label many times in a document.  This, to my opinion, only confuse readers :-(.